# load more button position always too far down from what it is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a load more button that load 10 new hidden div's on click, the problem is that i have 40 hidden div's and the button is setting at the end of the 40's div even when they are hidden, i just want it's position to be directly under the last div shown so when you click it it should load 10 more hidden div's and go down directly to set under the last new shown div. any idea's?

here is the html code(not that the hidden div'd that should show up on button click are the div's of the 's:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leb news.css">

<title> leb news</title>
</head>
<div class="all" dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<body>

<div class="header">
<h1>
```

اخبار لبنان

```
<img  src="paper.gif" alt="paper" height="115" />
```

LebNews

```
</h1>
</div>
<div class="clockall">
<div class="clock">
<div class="list">
<TABLE id="T_Menu" height="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="181" border="0" style="float: right">
                            <TD height="100%" vAlign="top" rowSpan="2" width="181" align="center">
<TABLE id="T_Menu" height="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="181" border="0">
<TR>
    <TD style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(Images/Menu/bgd.gif); BACKGROUND-ATTACHMENT: fixed; BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat; BACKGROUND-POSITION: left top"
        vAlign="top" align="center" bgColor="transparent" height="100%">     <TABLE id="T_Menu" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="80%" border="0">
            <TR>
                <TD vAlign="middle" align="center" height="100"><BR>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD align="center"><table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Menu1_Ad_menu" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr align="Center" style="color:#ffa500;background-color:#ffa500;border-width:0px;border-style:Groove;font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;">
    <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="Menu1:Ad_menu:_ctl1:ad_button" value="الرئيسية" id="Menu1_Ad_menu__ctl1_ad_button" style="color:#2C00A8;background-color:Transparent;border-color:#2C00A8;border-width:0px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold;width:150px;" /> 
                                </td>
</tr><tr style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:10pt;">
    <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="Menu1:Ad_menu:_ctl2:ad_button" value="اخبار" id="Menu1_Ad_menu__ctl2_ad_button" style="color:#2C00A8;background-color:Transparent;border-color:#2C00A8;border-width:0px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold;width:150px;" />
                                </td>
</tr><tr style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:10pt;">
    <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="Menu1:Ad_menu:_ctl3:ad_button" value="فن" id="Menu1_Ad_menu__ctl3_ad_button" style="color:#2C00A8;background-color:Transparent;border-color:#2C00A8;border-width:0px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold;width:150px;" />
                                </td>
</tr><tr style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:10pt;">
    <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="Menu1:Ad_menu:_ctl4:ad_button" value="رياضة" id="Menu1_Ad_menu__ctl4_ad_button" style="color:#2C00A8;background-color:Transparent;border-color:#2C00A8;border-width:0px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold;width:150px;" />
                                </td>
</tr><tr style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:10pt;">
    <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="Menu1:Ad_menu:_ctl5:ad_button" value="أدب" id="Menu1_Ad_menu__ctl5_ad_button" style="color:#2C00A8;background-color:Transparent;border-color:#2C00A8;border-width:0px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold;width:150px;" />
                                </td>
    </tr><tr style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:10pt;">
    <td>

  </table>
</table>
</table>
</table>
</div>
<div class="article" align="right" style="display: inline-block;" > 
<br>
<div class="27" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="28" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="29" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="30" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
 </a>
 </article>
 </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="31" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="32" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2" >
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="33" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="34" style="display:none; border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px; border-height:150px">
<article>
<a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
    <img src="paper.gif" alt="article title" align="right" border="2">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>Short description</p>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<div class="button">
<button type="button" name="more" id="load">More</button>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is the jquery of the button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").slice(0, 14).show(); // select the first ten
$("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
   $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show();
      // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
    if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
       alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left

    }
});
})
```

and the css :

```
 html { 
 background: url(32784_FLS_W01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

}

.header h1{
position: absolute;
/*background-color:#C63D0F; */
background-color:transparent;
padding:50px;
padding-left:250px;
padding-right:200px;
margin-left:65px;
margin-right:65px; 
font-size:80px;



 /*  vertical-align: top; */

}
.all {
width: 1370px;
/*height: auto;*/


}

.list {
```

padding-top:0px;
   padding-right:65px;

```
}


.article img{
height:150px;
width:150px;
border:"5";


 }
.article p{
width:800px;
height:65px;
font-size:16pt;
color:black;
text-decoration: none;
}
.article{
padding-top:0px;
/*overflow:hidden;*/

}

ul #mylist li{ list-style-type: none;
}
#mylist li{display:none;}
ul #mylist li img{
height:150px;
width:150px;
border="5";
}


#load {
/*  position: fixed; */
height: 30px; 

width: 100%; 
margin-top:0px;
overflow:hidden;

}
```

i really tried too many things in css to make it work but it seems that it should be worked jquery or javascript. hope somebody can help.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/3u46oh39/4/

working sample, off the top of my head, your class for

```
<div class=<missing quote>button">
<button type="button" name="more" id="load">More</button>

</div>
```

isn't quoted, but other than that you should post the real code

Comment: am not using this class anyways so the missing " has nothing to do with the solution, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and there is nothing wrong, maybe instead of this line

---

```
$("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show();
```

your can tried this

```
 $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).css('display','block');
```

If this doesnt work, you could tried pasting all your css and i could check it out what wrong, maybe another class is interfering with your button. Good luck

Comment: no didnt work, still have space between the last div shown and the button. ill show all my css, but am afraid that i also style inside the html so it could be something there not in the css. ill edit my post and put the whole code.

Comment: i edited my post and now it has all the code plz check it up

Comment: please help me if you have any idea am not able to solve it and there is no answer anywhere around, i took the code of the hidden div's and the button and tried it alone and faced the same problem, the problem is not related to anything out side.

Comment: The solution could be easy if you decided to solve all by CSS and not by style in the HTML. Believe me, it would be really easy.This is what you can do..... 1) Create a class in css that hide elements ... 2) When click in the button, assign that class to the next 10 divs. That simple, nothing in the css or the HTML is affecting the button. Git it a try.

Comment: so should i remove the display non from every article and put a dive that includes all the article and put the display for its class in the css>

Comment: Yes, you should put just a container display: block position: relative, width: 100%, for the container, and then when the button is clicked you may assing a class name .show each article (noticed that by default the articles should be display:none)

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".article > div").slice(0, 10).show(); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".article > div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show();
          // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($(".article > div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs   still exist
           alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
    
        }
    });
    })